# Can't import form classes in uno libreoffice

Tags: python, uno, libreoffice-writer

I'm actually trying to make python macro for Libreoffice writer, and I'm stuck with a weird issue. I'm new to this and english is not my native, so maybe I did not formulate my issue well but I did not find any solution on the web, and the python's UNO API is... well, very well documented -_-.

Here is my problem. I wanted to make some strong typing for the function of my python module so then I ensure they are well used. My functions and classes use some form items to bind them authomatically, and when I try to import their type, uno reject me with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\uno.py", line 423, in _uno_import
  raise uno_import_exc
File "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\uno.py", line 346, in _uno_import
  return _builtin_import(name, *optargs, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'com' (or 'com.sun.star.form.component.CommandButton' is unknown)
```

Long story short, uno reject my imports when it comes from "form" module of "com.sun.star").
To be more precise, I tried in the python module and in the APSO Python Interpreter

If anyone has any idea. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create a `CommandButton` and verify what kind of object it is.

```
ctx = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext()
smgr = ctx.getServiceManager()
button = smgr.createInstance('com.sun.star.form.component.CommandButton')
if button.supportsService('com.sun.star.form.component.CommandButton'):
    ## Yes, the object is a CommandButton.
```

Comment: OK super, thats what I was expecting, in a way. Thank you !